# Flot bar graph with AJAX data

Tags: jquery, flot

I have an issue with Flot charts and the data that is coming from AJAX. Basically I created arrays to display the graph but somehow I see the axis label but no data. Also how can I do a stacked or a bar graph?

Edit: Or can anybody tell me how to display data in flot using AJAX with labels on the x-axis. You can see the code here http://jsfiddle.net/DaG5W/284/. Anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the code I used.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(output) {
    var calendar, count, fieldNames, i, j, values, xAxis;
    fieldNames = new Array();
    i = 0;
    while (i < output.length) {
      if (fieldNames.indexOf(output[i].FieldName) < 0) {
        fieldNames.push(output[i].FieldName);
      }
      i++;
    }
    calendar = new Array();
    i = 0;
    while (i < output.length) {
      if (calendar.indexOf(output[i].Calendar) < 0) {
        calendar.push(output[i].Calendar);
      }
      i++;
    }
    xAxis = [];
    i = 0;
    while (i < calendar.length) {
      xAxis.push([parseInt(i + 1), calendar[i]]);
      i++;
    }
    data = [];
    i = 0;
    while (i < fieldNames.length) {
      values = [];
      count = 0;
      j = 0;
      while (j < output.length) {
        if (fieldNames[i] === output[j].FieldName) {
          count++;
          values.push([parseInt(count), parseInt(output[j].Totals)]);
        }
        j++;
      }
      data.push([
        {
          label: fieldNames[i].toString(),
          data: values,
          bars: {
            show: true
          },
          lines: {
            show: false
          }
        }
      ]);
    }
    return i++;
  });
  options = {
    xaxis: {
      ticks: xAxis
    }
  };
  plot = $.plot($("#div"), [data], options);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close to a working solution.  All you've done incorrectly is to nest a few too many arrays in 2 places:

```
  data.push([
    {
      label: fieldNames[i].toString(),
      data: values,
      bars: {
        show: true
      },
      lines: {
        show: false
      }
    }
  ]);
```

No need for the `[]` around your series object.

```
plot = $.plot($("#div"), [data], options);
```

Similarly here, no need for `[]` around `data`.  After that, it will graph.  See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/DaG5W/291/